# What is the difference between updates via terminal and those that appear in ubuntu software?

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

1. Are the same thing?
2. If they are the same thing, why when I update via the terminal, do the update options continue in Ubuntu Software?
3. Can I use both?

Comment: Yes. Both the command line tools (`apt`, `apt-get`, `apt-cache`) and the GUI tools install software, and update your system's packaging database. Updated software is updated software, whichever method you use.

Comment: The GUI will also additionally update snaps, IIRC. You need to run `snap refresh` or something like that for doing that via the terminal.

Comment: ... Also how do you "update" via terminal as for example `apt update` will only update the local copy of packages information but will not install them ... You'll need to run `apt upgrade` to install the updated packages that are managed by APT for example.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Are the same thing?

These are exactly the same updates, performed in the backend by the same software that is part of the the APT packaging system, though through different front end tools.

Note that the timing by which both tools present updates may differ between the tools. In other words, updates listed by querying the terminal may be different from those listed in the graphical tool. For a long time, the graphical software manager had a phased software rollout in place, and the terminal not. With a phased rollout, not all updates are released to all users at the same time. Recently, such phased rollout has also been implemented in the terminal tools.

> 2. If they are the same thing, why when I update via the terminal, do the update options continue in Ubuntu Software?

Normally that is not possible. A running update process will block the system and prevent other tools from running at the same time.

> 3. Can I use both?

Yes, you can, but do not attempt to use them at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the answer.